# Сайт показывающий шаги выполнения Python скрипта

Tags: python

Однажды натыкался на сайт, который показывал шаги выполнения Python скрипта, но забыл сохранить его адрес. Кто нибудь знает о подобном сайте ? Прошу прощения за оффтоп.

Comment: http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit ?

Comment: Да, @MaxU, это он, тот самый. Спасибо!

Comment: практически в каждом IDE можно отладчик запустить и по шагам выполнить (отображение самое разное может быть)

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл ! http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.

Ещё раз прошу прощения.